# Get Zend Framework Web Service via Android

Tags: android, web-services, apache-flex, zend-framework

How can I get the web service of a web application made in Flex and Zend Framework with PHP to be consumed by my Android Application? I was wondering if I can just use the existing web service of our web application rather than creating a separate one for my Android app to use. In that way, the web services should only be edited/created once rather than creating separate services for both Android and the web app. Is there an XML or JSON like output from Zend?

Comment: which ZF version do you use?

Comment: The Zend Framework version is 1.11.2